# send image base64 encoded date using ajax as parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how can i send base64 image data that store in jquery variable via ajax as parameters to php file?

i have below code working for small string but for large string getting 414 error "414 Request-URI Too Large".

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        //url:'../function.php/?imagestr='+string,
        url:'../function.php',
        data: "{imagestr:'" + string + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        //dataType: 'text',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove imagestr part from `url` as you already sending it in `data`.

Comment: yes, i already try with this but it's not working...for larger string..as you can see i also try with dataType as text

for long string i have error like 414

Comment: Try using like : data: { imagestr:  string}. Let me know if that works

Comment: ok, i try with  data: { imagestr: string}. but as i told you it's working for small data but for large data not working..
what exactly haapned is .... i want to upload image , but before upload i want to crop image and then submit it.so that when user browse file i set as preview as base64, but for large size of image like 1000x2000 i want to resize them first before crop..

Comment: is there any way or function in jquery that resize base64 image ?

Comment: Try removing contentType: "application/json" and then try